# Classformat error while trying to deploy WAR into jboss eap 6.4

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, jboss6.x

We are deploying our JSF application with primefaces into JBOSS-EAP-6.4. We are getting ClassFormatError with DataModel when the War is deployed into the server.

JSF - 2.2.11, Primefaces 6.0
I have already tried the solution provided here -https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/WhatsTheCauseOfThisExceptionJavalangClassFormatErrorAbsentCode 
But this error is happening with Primefaces LazyDataModel class which uses DataModel from faces library.
This is my pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
      <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
      <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
      <version>1.14</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
      <version>6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
      <artifactId>afterwork</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
      <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
      <version>6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
      <artifactId>resources-ckeditor</artifactId>
      <version>6.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/faces/model/DataModel

Comment: Your pom is wrong... You have the API and JSF impl in your war. They should be profivided, as should all other java-ee api and implementation UNLESS you want it in your war for a reason but that could still be a big part of the problem

Comment: I think I got it. But even after applying provided scope, I am running into this error in Jboss deployment.